# use activecell to go n rows below in PHPEXCEL

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to put a value in the cell B24

I'm using this code :

```
$active_cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSelectedCell('B'.(17+$arr_periodes[2]));
```

Then, I would like to go 4 lines below

How can I use $active_cell to go 4 rows below ?

I tried OFFSET, it doesn't work :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSelectedCell($active_cell:OFFSET($arr_periodes[1]),'x');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did, it's working :

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(($arr_periodes[2]+1),17+($arr_periodes[1]),'X');
```

Answer (score 1):

To put a value in cell B24

```
$active_cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('B24', 'Value that I want to put in the cell', true);
```

To set the active cell 4 cells below B24

```
$rc = PHPExcel_Cell:coordinateFromString($active_cell->getCoordinate());
$rc[1] += 4;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setSelectedCell(
        implode($rc)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you.  The first part of your code works.  For the second part, I guess you forgot one : ? PHPExcel_Cell::  The valu stills in the B24, it doesn't move.

Comment: Then perhaps you should explain what it is you are actually trying to do.... The value in B24 won't automatically move anywhere, you've set it for B24, so that's where it stays..... if you want to add new rows before row 24, then you need to use `insertNewRowBefore()`... that's the only way that B24 can become B28

Comment: Setting an active cell doesn't change any cells; it simply sets the cell that the cursor will be in when a saved excel file is opened in MS Excel